# Run Ubuntu No Monitor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote, vnc, remote-desktop

I would like to run an Ubuntu (18.0.4) desktop with no monitor/keyboard attached, and access it via VNC (or Remote Desktop) from a Windows 10 Pro machine. I have installed VNC Viewer on Windows and enabled remote access from Linux. It all works, but not until I log on to the Linux box from an actual keyboard - which defeats the purpose. In other words, Linux will let me log in remotely only after I am logged in physically.

I followed instructions to [set up Linux for remote access](https://www.howtoforge.com/configure-remote-access-to-your-ubuntu-desktop), including the bit about "allowing unencrypted connections", but then I realized that those are instructions for allowing an external user to view/control *the same session* as a logged-on user, as opposed to allowing an external user to start their own session.

What do I need to do to have the Linux-side start up and be ready for connections without the need to attach a physical keyboard? For instance, perhaps I need to make sure that VNC Server starts as soon as the Linux machine boots, etc.

It does not need to be VNC. I can work in the Windows remote desktop window as well. I just want to access this Linux machine without attaching a keyboard/mouse/monitor.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looks like you need to start your vncserver as a service you can create an unit file for that and enable it with
 `systemd enable myservicestuff`

Look at the 4th step:

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: For the sake of people who visit here after the link breaks, please import the relevant commands into your answer, so that your answer is self-contained. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

If you are using a pro version of Windows, just fire up Windows' *Remote Desktop Connection*, which will prompt you for remote server's IP address, after connecting to the remote machine, you will be prompted for login info. Let me know if this works.

Comment: OP's problem is not connecting from Windows - it's having everything ready on the Linux side before connecting